# I need to know the dates this uniform was used

Tags: united-states, identification, uniform

[image]

Attached is a picture of my relative in a USA military uniform.  I would like to know when this uniform was in use and what branch of service and rank the soldier held.

Comment: [Link](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:Ce_167AWYovzHYaIjVE-3IKXm).

Comment: @Elizabeth Brown   What is the evidence the person is a relative of yours?  What is the evidence that his uniform is military instead of merly inspired by miitary uniforms?  What is the evidence that it is a USA uniform?  Your answers could help those who want to help you identify it.

Comment: This uniform bears a *strong* resemblance to those worn by [71st NY state militia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/71st_New_York_Infantry_Regiment), in the pre civil war and civil war era. The shako style helm in the pic seems to show a star on the front, similar to [this](https://www.horsesoldier.com/products/29347), the jacket is also quite similar to one depicted [from a book on Ebay](https://www.ebay.com/itm/202909656185), and from a civil war forum [here](https://civilwartalk.com/threads/71st-regiment-new-york-militia.137806). The sleeve cuffs don't appear to be a match however.

Comment: There were hundreds of state volunteer/militia units formed in this era, each having some freedom on uniform styles. If you have more precise location information concerning where your ancestor lived between 1850 and 1870, it might help narrow down the possibilities. You can use the [edit](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/65726/edit) key to add further details to your question.

Comment: As JustCal points out this is a state militia type uniform. It is NOT a regulation US Army uniform.  From stripes on the sleeve, probably a good bet he is a sergeant.  The sword is not of the heavier type one would associate with cavalry, rather a light NCO type (remember, sergeant stripes) of infantry.  So, you re probably looking for a militia unit, probably of well-to-do young men from a, for the times, large metropolitan area.  Could be pre or post CW.  Militia units were part & parcel of the mid to upper class social scene in many cities.  One had to be able to afford the uniform.

Comment: Additional - Militia units were not required to outfit themselves as the US Army, especially.  For example, the Richmond Light Infantry Blues (with a smattering of other units), see  https://www.google.com/search?q=richmond+light+infantry+blues+uniform&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS892US892&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=DStCDakFsOpXyM%252CIQqenHa-NOn8wM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQ3K_3NvqnIc8CUOaH_tf12vUrtUw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjam8qPkqTyAhUBFVkFHdSNAJcQ9QF6BAgREAE#imgrc=DStCDakFsOpXyM